# How to get of a static object for hold for every logged user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop, asp.net-mvc-4

I am struggled in a task I cannot find the solution

I have a asp net mvc 4 application that I have implemented a permission system.
This app has an static object that is filled with permissions information when the user log-in.

It creates a new object for each user as soon as it logs-in

This object is checked every time the users invoke a action.

But in the case the administrator change some permission rule I need to find a way to propagate this change to all logged users.
At the moment the user needs to log-out and log-in again to the change take effect.

I am able to get all current logged users. But how to get the static object associated to each user? The code is a bit big but it is working... I just need to find a way to get hold of it for each logged user

**This is the object:**

**model:**

```
public static class permissionTemp
{
    public static Guid userGuid        { get; set; }
    public static string[] grupos      { get; set; }
    public static string[] permissoes  { get; set; }
}
```

**controller:**

```
public bool createPermissionObject(Guid userID, string username)
{
    using (gedaiappEntities context = new gedaiappEntities())
    {
        //Cria objeto global de permissões
        gedaiapp.Models.permissionTemp.userGuid = userID;
        //Resgata todos os grupos do usuário
        gedaiapp.Models.permissionTemp.grupos = Roles.GetRolesForUser(username);

        List<string> c = new List<string>();
        //Primeiro carrega permissões dos Grupos atribuidos ao usuário
        foreach (var grupo in gedaiapp.Models.permissionTemp.grupos)
        {
            //Recupera id do grupo
            var grpId = (from a in context.aspnet_Roles
                            where a.RoleName == grupo
                            select a.RoleId).First();

            //Resgata todas as permissões do grupo
            var permGrpIdsObj = from a in context.sistema_permissoes_grupos
                                where a.groupId == grpId
                                select a.idPermissao;

            if (permGrpIdsObj.Any())
            {
                var permGrpIdsLst = permGrpIdsObj.ToList();
                foreach (var permGrpId in permGrpIdsLst)
                {
                    var permName = (from a in context.aspnet_Roles
                                    where a.RoleId == permGrpId
                                    select a.RoleName).First();

                    c.Add(permName);
                }
            }
        }

        //Por último carrega as permissões individuais do usuário
        var permUsrIdsObj = from a in context.sistema_permissoes_usuarios
                            where a.userGuid == userID
                            select a.idPermissao;

        if (permUsrIdsObj.Any())
        {

            var permUsrIds = permUsrIdsObj.ToList();
            foreach (var permUsrId in permUsrIds)
            {
                var perm = (from a in context.aspnet_Roles
                            where a.RoleId == permUsrId
                            select a.RoleName).First();
                c.Add(perm);
            }
        }

        //Atribui todas as permissões encontradas (GRUPO e INDIVIDUAIS) para o modelo
        gedaiapp.Models.permissionTemp.permissoes = c.ToArray();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why would you be using a static class to store user-instance data?  That will scale to exactly one user.

Comment: Why not change the static class to a public class and create a `List<permissionTemp>`

Comment: In case you do not know, your static class `permissionTemp` is being shared amongst all of the logged in users, it is not creating a new one per user.

Comment: @DJKRAZE I have just notice that... so If I create a public class for permission, how can I access those oobjects for the logged users if a administrator make changes in the permission rule?

Comment: You've stumbled across the reason that many applications force you to log out and log back in after permissions change. The easiest way to accomplish what you want is to not cache the permissions anywhere. Look them up fresh when you need them. Then, when your admin interface saves the permissions to the repository, you know the application will always use the most up-to-date permissions. This is the easiest, but of course, it is also the least performant in terms of speed.

Answer (score 0):

Change static to normal class.

```
public class permissionTemp
{
    public Guid userGuid        { get; set; }
    public string[] grupos      { get; set; }
    public string[] permissoes  { get; set; }
}
```

Create the object and populate it. Also, consider changing return type to permissionTemp instead of bool. And I don't know your intention of returning bool result, since you already populating userID in the beginning and always returning true.

```
public **permissionTemp** createPermissionObject(Guid userID, string username)
{
    var objPermission = new permissionTemp();
    using (gedaiappEntities context = new gedaiappEntities())
    {        

       //Cria objeto global de permissões
        objPermission.userGuid = userID;
        //
        objPermission.grupos = Roles.GetRolesForUser(username);

        ....

        objPermission.permissoes = c.ToArray();
    }
    return objPermission;
}
```

**Edit**

It can be stored in session or profile when user logs into the application and use it in rest of the application. But meanwhile, if admin changes the permissions, it will be applied on user next login.

**Edit**

I understood what you are trying to achieve with static list. Consider this situation,  static list is populated with all users permissions and admin changes the permission, the static list wont get updated until NEW user logs-in. Because static list is not intended to have updated data from database, it remains in the local cache.

Try by using SQLCacheDependecy on permissions table, and handle it's onchange event to update the session.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already managed to have that working. I am looking for a way to changes take effect at runtime. I don´t want to wait till the next login to get the new permissions. Am I asking something absurd or there is a  way even if it is complicated? I was thinking I could create a permission static list and then update that list every time permissions changes. When the user log-out it just destroy an item from this list. What you think?